# Creating a HTML/JS "plugin" in ES6 - how to refresh DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-modules

I am currently in the process of learning ES6. I'm trying to create a carousel which I would usually have written as a JQuery plugin but now instead writing it as an ES6 module so that it can be added to a page's JS using the import keyword.

As the carousel has slides which are absolutely positioned on top of each other, a calculation is done within the JS to determine the tallest carousel slide height and then apply this height to the carousel's UL element.

The module grabs several elements from the DOM within the constructor such as the containing DIV of all carousel elements, the UL of the carousel slides, etc.

```
class Carousel {
    // set up instance variables
    constructor (options) {

        this.element = options.element;
        this.carousel = options.element.querySelectorAll('ul');
        this.carouselSlides = this.carousel[0].children;
        this.carouselHeight = 0;
    }

    resize () {
        console.log(this.carouselSlides);

        //Get tallest slide
        Array.prototype.map.call( this.carouselSlides, ( slide ) => {
            this.carouselHeight = (slide.offsetHeight > this.carouselHeight) ? slide.offsetHeight : this.carouselHeight;
        });

        //Set the height of the carousel to the height of its tallest slide
        this.carousel[0].style.height = this.carouselHeight+'px';

    }

    // initial set up
    setup () {
        this.resize();
        window.onresize = this.resize;
    }



}


module.exports = Carousel;
```

As this height will need to be adjusted as the browser width gets smaller I have tried to call the function which does this calculation on window.onresize.

However this does not work. I believe it is because the dom nodes that were assigned to variables in the constructor are cached at their current widths and heights and so the resize function does not use their new values in its calculation.

**How can I adjust my code to prevent this caching issue?**

Below is a simplified Codepen of my code so far. (I had to add the Carousel module code in with the main script just for Codepen):

http://codepen.io/decodedcreative/pen/vXzGpE/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is related to the context of `this`. When you assign the callback to the `window.resize` event, the this is changed to the `window`:

```
window.onresize = this.resize;
```

When the callback is called, `this.carouselSlides` is undefined because the window doesn't have this property (look at the console to see the errors).

To prevent this problem, bind the callback to the original `this` (the class instance):

```
window.onresize = this.resize.bind(this);
```

You can see it in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/pEOEOb).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it looks like the issue is still occurring in the Codepen you sent in your solution. I want the height of the UL to update as the browser is resized.

Comment: That's a flaw in your logic. The height of the UL is 0 before you set it, after you set it it's `700px`. The same as the images. That will never change, as   the images height is not affected by anything in your code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok I've updated my CodePen: http://codepen.io/decodedcreative/pen/vXzGpE/. I realised that I needed to set the height of the UL back to 0 again at the end of the Resize function otherwise it would not work properly when it needed to run the second/third/fourth times. This seems to work fine now if there is one carousel on the page. But breaks if there are two or more. How do I keep the variables of each instance of the carousel separate? As I suspect that this is what is causing the issue?

Comment: They are separated. The problem is the event handler - you can set only one the way you're doing it. You can use `.addEventListener() ` instead or use one resize, and call all `carousel.resize` handlers in it.

Comment: Cool thanks for all this help. Much appreciated. Not sure I'm following with your last message though. Which event handler could I change to addEventListener? the window.onresize?

Comment: Actually I've worked out what you meant: window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this)); Seems to work. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there were a couple of issues with my code. Thanks to Ori Drori's help I got to the bottom of them. Here is the fixed code:

```
class Carousel {
    // set up instance variables
    constructor (options) {

        this.element = options.element;
        this.carousel = options.element.querySelectorAll('ul');
        this.carouselSlides = this.carousel[0].children;
        this.carouselHeight = 0;

    }

    resize () {

        //Get tallest slide
        Array.prototype.map.call( this.carouselSlides, ( slide ) => {
            this.carouselHeight = (slide.offsetHeight > this.carouselHeight) ? slide.offsetHeight : this.carouselHeight;
        });

        //Set the height of the carousel to the height of its tallest slide
        this.carousel[0].style.height = this.carouselHeight+'px';

        //Reset the height of the carousel to zero
        this.carouselHeight = 0;

     }

     // initial set up
     setup () {
         this.resize();
         window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
     }



}
```

Hopefully this helps someone!